# How to disable upload file pdf with active content?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I'm try to protect my system by reject user upload file if that file contain active content like: javascript, form field, media, ...
Can you guys suggest me any library or third party to support that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) to check whether a file contains active content:

1. Check if PdfDocument.SharedScripts collection contains any scripts.
2. Check PdfDocument.GetWidgets() collection to detect form fields and annotations.
3. Check interactive actions in certain objects:

   - PdfDocument.OnOpenDocument property
   - PdfDocument.OutlineRoot and its child objects. Use PdfOutlineItem.Action property.
   - Actions in controls (PdfControl.On* properties)
   - Action area (widgets of PdfActionArea type)